# CMake - Pass a list as a string to add_custom_target for CMake script

Tags: cmake

`add_custom_target` seems to be 'unpacking' lists when I don't want it to.  Take this `add_custom_target` that I'm using to invoke a CMake script:

```
message(STATUS "Sources: ${ARGS_SOURCES}")
add_custom_target(${ARGS_TARGET}
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND}
            -DSOURCES="${ARGS_SOURCES}"
            -DOUTPUT_DIR="${ARGS_OUTPUT_DIR}"
            -P "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake/translation_generator/translation_generator_script.cmake"
    SOURCES ${ARGS_SOURCES}
            "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake/translation_generator/translation_generator_script.cmake")
```

The message output is what I'm expecting, a list of paths separated by semi-colons.

```
-- Sources: /home/cmannett85/workspace/arg_router/examples/resources/simple_ml_gen/en_GB.toml;/home/cmannett85/workspace/arg_router/examples/resources/simple_ml_gen/fr.toml;/home/cmannett85/workspace/arg_router/examples/resources/simple_ml_gen/ja.toml
```

However when the script is invoked, I get this:

```
/usr/bin/cmake -DSOURCES="/home/cmannett85/workspace/arg_router/examples/resources/simple_ml_gen/en_GB.toml /home/cmannett85/workspace/arg_router/examples/resources/simple_ml_gen/fr.toml /home/cmannett85/workspace/arg_router/examples/resources/simple_ml_gen/ja.toml" ...
```

It's unpacked the list into a space separated string - this is not what I want.

I attempted to use the `VERBATIM` flag but it completely mangled the invocation:

```
/usr/bin/cmake -DSOURCES=\"/home/cmannett85/workspace/arg_router/examples/resources/simple_ml_gen/en_GB.toml /home/cmannett85/workspace/arg_router/examples/resources/simple_ml_gen/fr.toml /home/cmannett85/workspace/arg_router/examples/resources/simple_ml_gen/ja.toml\" ...
```

It's escaping the double quotes.  If I remove them:

```
/usr/bin/cmake -DSOURCES=/home/cmannett85/workspace/arg_router/examples/resources/simple_ml_gen/en_GB.toml /home/cmannett85/workspace/arg_router/examples/resources/simple_ml_gen/fr.toml /home/cmannett85/workspace/arg_router/examples/resources/simple_ml_gen/ja.toml ...
```

It keeps the spaces, breaking the called script.  I also tried:

```
list(JOIN ARGS_SOURCES ";" ARGS_SOURCES)
```

But the unpacking appears to happen in the `add_custom_target` processing, so this made no difference.

So my question is: How do I pass a list to a `add_custom_target` command, as a semi-colon separated string?

Comment: The command line parameter needs to be surrounded by the quotes completely. CMake is not the only program that requires this: `"-DSOURCES=${ARGS_SOURCES}"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CMake quoting is confusing. For example: `"this"` is quoted. For example: `th"is"` is *not* quoted, and `"` are taken literally.

In your example, `-DSOURCES="${ARGS_SOURCES}"` `"` are literal. So `ARGS_SOURCES` is split, as it is an array, and your program receives multiple arguments like `'-DSOURCES="elem1' 'elem2' 'elem3' 'elem4"'` *with the `"` quotes*.

If you want to quote in CMake, the first character has to be `"` and the last character has to be `"`. Just like you did with `"Sources: ${ARGS_SOURCES}"`.

```
"-DSOURCES=${ARGS_SOURCES}"
```